# Automatically uncompress Zstd archives

Tags: untagged

Emacs has this very nice functionality that it automatically decompresses ".gz" / ".tar.gz" archives upon opening them (e.g. `C-x f logs.gz`).

I'd like to extend this functionality so Emacs also performs this for [Zstd archives](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/).

Can anyone point me in the direction towards which setting I need to customize? I'm sure it's just a `add-to-list` or `add-hook` away :-)

Comment: AFAIK (and I may not know enough - be forewarned), all you need to do is add the file suffix for such files to `jka-compr-load-suffixes` and add an entry to handle such files to `jka-compr-compression-info-list`. Do `C-h v <variable>` on each of these two variables and see what you need to do.

Comment: Wich is your emacs version? In mine, 28.2 zstd archives are mentioned in `jka-compr-compression-info-list`. Make sure you have the correct compression and decompression programs available in `exec-path`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @NickD and @matteol for pointing me in the direction of `jka-compr-compression-info-list`.
In Emacs 28, this list indeed contains an entry for Zstandard archives, but only for file endings `*.zst` - hence my files named `example.log.zstd` were not picked up by Emacs.
Since `zst` is the official file extension for Zstandard files (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8878), I'll fix the program that generated these "incorrectly" named files.

If anyone else still wants to add new file endings to the list, here's how to do it:

```
(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list
             ["\\.zstd\\'"
              "zstd compressing" "zstd" ("-c", "-q")
              "zstd decompressing" "zstd" ("-c", "-q", "-d")
              nil t])
```

Based on the upstream implementation: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/4b3de748b0b04407d2492500c77905de56de1180/lisp/jka-cmpr-hook.el#L257-L260